# Do functions of form $y=mx+b$ adhere to additive property of principle of superposition

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm referring to the definition that a function is additive if $f(x_1 + x_2) =f(x_1)+f(x_2)$.

I'd imagine $y=mx+b$ is additive since its linear.

But if $f(x)=mx+b$. $f(x_1+x_2)=m(x_1+x_2)+b=mx_1+mx_2+b$. However, $f(x_1)+f(x_2)=mx_1+b+mx_2+b=mx_1+mx_2+2b$ which isn't the same as $mx_1+mx_2+b$. Since $b$ isn't equal to $2b$.

So is it correct to say that $y=mx+b$ doesn't satisfy the additive property?

Comment: $y = mx + b$ does not satisfy the superposition property (unless $b = 0$).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are conflating two different meaning of the word, "linear". We call a polynomial linear if it is of degree one, that is, if it is $mx+b$ for some $m,b$. We call a transformation linear if it satisfies $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$ and $T(ax)=aT(x)$.

Comment: In that first sense, "polynomially linear" is also called "affine linear".